# Search Method with pagination result

Tags: laravel

I made a search method (GET) with some filters, the only problem that i have is when i run the search result i get the results with pagination with the adresse like :

> search?q=&type_licence_id=&activite_licence_id=&structure_id=8

when i click on page 2 for exemple i have :

> search?page=2

So it's display me anymore the results from the search query.

Maybe i done something wrong on my controller ? Hope someone could help me , thanks a lot in advance

here my controller :

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {

        $structure = Structure::select('num_structure', 'nom_structure' , 'id')

            ->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
                return [$i->id => $i->num_structure.' - '.$i->nom_structure];
            });

        $activite = ActiviteLicencie::pluck('lb_activite' , 'id');
        $type_licence = Type_licence::pluck('lb_type' , 'id');

        $query = Licencies::query();

        $filters = [
            'type_licence_id' => 'type_licence_id',
            'activite_licence_id' => 'activite_licencie_id',
            'structure_id' => 'structure_id',

        ];

        foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
            $query->when($request->{$key}, function ($query, $value) use ($column) {
                $query->where($column, $value);
            });

        }

        $licencies = $query->paginate(10);

        return view('licencie/recherche', compact('licencies' , 'structure' , 'activite' , 'type_licence'));

    }
```

Comment: So, do you need to get the filter query along with pagination ?

Comment: exactly !!!!!!!

Comment: Please try `$licencies->setPath($request->url());`

Comment: where should i need to add this line ?

Comment: Check out "Appending to pagination links" under the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: something like this : {{ $licencies->appends(['search' => ''])->links() }} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following in my blade template:

```
{{ $licencies->appends(Request::all())->links() }}
```

It appends all your request parameters to the pagination.

Check 'Appending To Pagination Links' on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results for information

Answer (score 0):

You could customize the Pagination URL by

```
$licencies = $query->paginate(10);

$licencies->setPath($request->fullUrlWithQuery());
```

Docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method_setPath